# Fundamental matrix solution remains invertible

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, determinant, fundamental-solution

Given a system of first-order differential equations that is written as
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \vec{x}(t) = A(t) \vec{x}(t)
$$

One usually looks at the related matrix differential equation
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \Psi(t) = A(t) \Psi(t)
$$

The difference being that $\vec{x}(t)$ is a column vector and $\Psi(t)$ is a square matrix. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_matrix_(linear_differential_equation)), the matrix solution is required to be invertible for all $t$. Suppose we start with linearly independent columns for $\Psi(0)$, how is it guaranteed that $\Psi(t)$ will remain linearly independent for all other $t$? Is there a short proof for it?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728757/can-a-set-of-solutions-mathbfx-1-dots-mathbfx-k-to-a-linear-system/4728784#4728784).

Comment: Thanks, both. @Gonçalo if you could make your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the columns of $\Psi(0)$ are linearly independent, then $\det(\Psi(0))\neq 0$. It follows from [Liouville's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula)
$$
\det(\Psi(t))=\det(\Psi(0))\exp\left(\int_0^t\operatorname{tr}A(s)\,ds\right)
$$
that $\det(\Psi(t))\neq 0$ too, hence the columns of $\Psi(t)$ are linearly independent.